# Python - why do I get this error converting date format?

Tags: python

I'm getting an error when I try to convert the date format into something mongodb understands a little better:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tdun0002\OneDrive - Synchronoss Technologies\Desktop\important_folders\Jokefire\git\jf_cloud_scripts\aws_scripts\python\aws_tools\ec2_mongo.py", line 516, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\tdun0002\OneDrive - Synchronoss Technologies\Desktop\important_folders\Jokefire\git\jf_cloud_scripts\aws_scripts\python\aws_tools\ec2_mongo.py", line 505, in main
    print_reports()
  File "C:\Users\tdun0002\OneDrive - Synchronoss Technologies\Desktop\important_folders\Jokefire\git\jf_cloud_scripts\aws_scripts\python\aws_tools\ec2_mongo.py", line 363, in print_reports
    inputDate = inputDate.strftime(format)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

This is my code:

```
def print_reports():
    inputDate = input("Enter the date in format 'dd/mm/yyyy': ")
    day,month,year = inputDate.split('/')
    isValidDate = True
    try:
        datetime(int(year),int(month),int(day))
    except ValueError :
        isValidDate = False

    format= "%m%d%Y"
    inputDate = inputDate.strftime(format)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887353/attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-strftime

Answer (score 1):

`inputDate` *is* a `str` object, not a `date` object.

`strftime()` is a method that is part of the `datetime` class. If you want to parse a string to a date, you need to do something like this:

```
inputDate = input("Enter the date in format 'dd/mm/yyyy': ")
my_date = datetime.strptime(inputDate,"%d/%m/%Y") # Notice that you can parse the date 
                                                  # directly, without splitting the values
print(my_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) # You can now output the date in any format you want
```